# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.4000.0

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Following error getting when generating report using crystal report-
The type of initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.

InnerException = {"Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.C...

did i need install crystal report setup for visual studio 2022

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.